# How to pass data got from useEffect down a component tree(got undefined)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, ref, use-ref

I want to make a specific calculation in Search component. To do this, I have to pass a buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue obtained in the Header component to a Search component. I get the desired value in the Header. However in the Search component it always gets undefined. Can't understand this behavior.

```
const Header = props => {
     const buttonSearchRef = useRef(null);

     let buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue;

     useEffect(() => {
         buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue = 
         ReactDOM.findDOMNode(buttonSearchRef.current).offsetLeft;
         console.log(buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue); //got the value
      })

   return (
      <div ref={buttonSearchRef}>He<div>
             <Search buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue= 
          {buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue} />
       ) 
     }

 const Search = (props) => {
     console.log(props.buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue)//got undefined WHY?
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is when you declare it first like this, its value will be undefined by default

```
 let buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue;
```

Then, it will pass this value first to `Search` component **before** the `useEffect` of `Header` is run. Thats why you get `undefined`.
AFter that, when the DOM is fully rendered, the ref is attached, useEffect runs and update `buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue`, but this is **not** a React state or props. Therefore, it not update `props.buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue` in `Search`, resulting it still keeps undefined.

A quick fix for this is to put `buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue` in a state

```
export const Header = (props) => {
  const buttonSearchRef = useRef(null);

  const [ buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue, setButtonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
      setButtonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(buttonSearchRef.current).offsetLeft);
      console.log('head', buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue); //got the value
  });

  return (<div>
    <div ref={buttonSearchRef}>He</div>
    <Search buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue={buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue}/></div>);
  }
```

now your `Search` component should log the console twice, with the second time printing out the value.

Answer (score 1):

You may have noticed that. Console log will print in order like:

> undefined

> 0

This mean `useEffect` always be called after `return` function.
I suggest you should have state for `buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue` to pass it child component. Put your variable dependencies will make effect to `buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue` in `useEffect`.

My demo:

```
const Search = (props) => {
    console.log('value'+ props.buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue)//got undefined WHY?
    return <div/>
}

const Header = props => {
    const buttonSearchRef = useRef(null);

    const [buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue, setButtonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        let buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(buttonSearchRef.current).offsetLeft;
        setButtonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue(buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue);
        console.log(buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue); //got the value
    }, [
        //put some dependencies will effect your buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue
    ])

    return <div>
            <div ref={buttonSearchRef}>He</div>
            <Search buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue={buttonSearchRefOffsetLeftValue} />
        </div>;
}
```

Comment: Adding a state made all the difference! Thank you!:)